# Adding custom css to default style.css (Underscores _S Wordpress theme)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, underscores-wp

I'm currently building a custom theme on top of the [_S Underscores Wordpress theme.](http://underscores.me/) One of the things I immediately did was remove all the content in the `style.css` file, as I want to create my own styling (largely using Bootstrap).

However, I can't seem to get certain attributes in the `style.css` to make changes to the html. For example, I'm trying to set the following `<h1>` tag to red. But it will not change.

`<h1 id="testOfContent">Test</h1>`

CSS (in the `style.css` file provided by Underscores):

```
#testOfContent {
    color: red;
}
```

However, the font remains black. How do you manipulate a wordpress theme (especially _S Underscores which is meant to be customizable) to use your own css? Any ideas as to why it won't register my own CSS?

Here's my `functions.php` file and how I'm loading the script:

```
function tlas_css() {
    // Enqueue bootstrap css
    wp_register_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css');

    // Enqueue custom stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tlas-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/tlas.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tlas-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tlas_css' );
```

Comment: You can always use the developer tools of browsers to determine which styles get applied to a specific element (and which don't), and where they are located. For example Firefox: http://getfirebug.com/css

Comment: Try `h1#testOfContent` instead of `#testOfContent`. You need to make sure either - or both - of two things: Make your rule at least as specific as the one you want to override; and if it's not **more** specific, make sure it's loaded after the other rule.

Comment: @connexo, no luck there unfortunately. Even tried adding `!important` just to see if anything could get it to work.

Comment: You have a link to the site? Or to the template in action where such an element can be found in?

Comment: @connexo Unfortunately I don't. This site is only running locally right now. The code snippet with the `<h1>` tag I posted above is in my `header.php`. I've tried posting this snippet in other files and still to no avail. Clearly something is interfering with my CSS, since I tried this on another site (basic html/css file combo) and it worked fine.

Comment: So how do you know the h1 has the given id?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );` which retrieves the URI of the current theme stylesheet.

Read more on [codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri)

Answer (score 0):

The workflow I prefer to customize and add to the css for the _s theme is by editing the .scss Sass files. Be sure to select the Advanced Options so you can tick the _sassify! check box if using the _s theme Generator at https://underscores.me/#generator

Then you can import the Bootstrap Sass you want since Bootstrap 4 is written with Sass. If you prefer using Bootstrap 3, you can find it's Sass ports as well.

If you're not sure how to build the Sass, I put together a Webpack 4 development workflow for the Sassify option included with the underscores Wordpress starter theme. Hope this helps https://jimfrenette.com/2018/08/completely-blank-no-css-_s-wordpress-starter-theme/

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Chrome, try to clear cache (ctrl+F5).
Or Open Dev tools > settings > preferences > network > disable cache (when dev tool is open)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:

```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourstyle' );
    function yourstyle() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'yourstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/yourstyle.css', array(), PARENT_THEME_VERSION );
    }
```